# Flutter local notifications doesn't grant permissions on Android

Tags: android

flutter_local_notifications doesn't show permissions dialog on Android API level 33. Tested with emulator. In AndroidManifest.xml file, I've defined the needed permission:

This is an example code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

Future<void> setup() async {
  final _localNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  const androidSetting = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
  const initSettings = InitializationSettings(android: androidSetting);

  await _localNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSettings).then((_) {
    debugPrint('setupPlugin: setup success');
  }).catchError((Object error) {
    debugPrint('Error: $error');
  });
  bool? granted = await _localNotificationsPlugin.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()?.requestPermission() ?? false;

  print('granted: $granted');
}

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  setup();
  runApp(myApp());
}

class myApp extends StatelessWidget {
    myApp({super.key});

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            child: Text('Notification test')
          )
        )
      );
    }

}
```